# multithreading in another unit in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a number crunching application in a unit called Execution that is called from the main form. Vey often the code in Execution.pas needs to run 10-15 times in a row and I am looking an efficient way to apply multi-threading, so that the calculations on the Execution unit run in parallel. A simplified version of the code is as follows:

Main Form with one Button1 in it:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Execution;

type
  TMainForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  MainForm1: TMainForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ExecutionThread: TThread;
  run_ID: integer;
begin
    for run_ID := 0 to 2 do
    begin
        ExecutionThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        begin
            Execution.CalculateSum;
        end);
        ExecutionThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
        ExecutionThread.Start;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Execution.pas unit:

```
unit Execution;

interface
uses System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs;

  procedure CalculateSum;
  procedure IncrementSum(var Sum: integer);

implementation

const
  NoOfTimes = 100;
var
  Sum: integer;

procedure CalculateSum;
var
  i: integer;
begin
    Sum := 0;
    for i := 0 to Pred(NoofTimes) do
    begin
        IncrementSum(Sum);
    end;
    ShowMessage('Sum = ' + IntToStr(Sum));
end;

procedure IncrementSum(var Sum: integer);
begin
    Inc(Sum);
    Sleep(10);
end;

end.
```

If I execute the simplified code, I get three messages with sums close to 300, but not 300 (285, 287, 289), which is expected, since all the threads change the same global variable Sum at the same time and sometimes the incrementations overlap.

Is there an easy way to allocate different memory to each thread, so that I get three messages with sums 100? Or do I have to hard code it myself, allocating different Execution variables in each thread?

Note that the original application that I have contains some thousands variables and records, hence I am looking for a fast way to do this without changing significantly the code (if there is any, of course).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is your responsibility to ensure that threads do not simultaneously operate on shared resources.  There are many ways to do this and hardcoding separate global variables for each thread is one way, albeit not a very elegant one.  Ideally you would encapsulate the required operation into a class which manages and contains the required state and which you can create any number of instances of.

Comment: Sadly, if your application is as poorly written as your example, there will be no easy way.  I've done this for a large, mostly non-OO legacy application (100% globals and spaghetti over hundreds of units) and the resulting `TThread` descendent required encapsulating over 300 previously global variables and arrays and required re-writing about 10,000 lines of previously global code into the new class.  It took months.  This is why developers generally have strong reactions to badly written code - because it makes a mess that leaves you with no option but a LOT of work to clean up.

Comment: Hence, the easiest way to do so is to create a class for all the calculations of Execution.pas, right? I was hoping that there is a simpler way for my case (without high hopes though, to be honest)

Comment: The code is separated and the interaction between the main form and Execution.pas takes place in a single procedure which passes the necessary data. The variables required in Execution.pas are all declared in Execution.pas, hence I could declare the variables for each thread relatively easily. At least, this I have taken care of. I was just wondering if there is an more automated way (from your response I realise that there is not). Many thanks for the prompt reply J.. !

Comment: You have placed the code in a Unit but a Unit is not a class that becomes the working object(s). Create a class from TThread, put your methods and variables in that class, create an instance of that class, call execute.  Override the create if you want to pass in parameters.  And never, ever update the GUI or call ShowMessage from inside a thread.  If you want the results, read it before you terminate the thread or add a call-back on terminate to the GUI so it can show the message or get the result.

Comment: Don't call `ShowMessage` (or anything that interacts with the UI) from a background thread!

Answer (score 0):

Don't write to the same variable from multiple threads without synchronization or you risk corrupting the data of that variable.

So instead of calling `IncrementSum(Sum)` in your thread call `Synchronize(IncrementSum(Sum))`.

This forces procedure IncrementSum to be executed within the scope of the main thread and thus prevents multiple of your worker threads to be modifying that variable at the same time and thus causing potential data damage.

Also you may want to avoid updating this global variable from each loop cycle of every of your worker threads. If you have 10 of your worker threads all waiting for global thread to update this global variable they might end up spending most of their time waiting for main thread to proces their `Synchronize` calls.

Se perhaps you should consider updating this global variable ever 10 or so cycles for instance. The number of cycles between you go and updating the global variable would depend on how fast each cycle is finished. faster the cycles are done more cycles it is work to wait before updating the global variable and thus reducing the number of `Synchronize` calls and thus putting less load on the main thread.

Comment: But OP does not want the separate threads to operate on the same variable.  They need the threads to operate on their own variables and the question is asking how to do that.

Comment: OP also wants the solution with least code refactoring. Using `Synchronize` calls would achieve this albeit not make best solution. Other solution would be to abandon the use of Anonymous Threads and instead derive its own TThread class which would contain its own field for counting cycles. But OP also stated that his real project has numerous global variables that are currently all accessed by his worker threads. This would mean that his TThread class would need to have multiple fields and he would have to make multiple changes in his code to use those fields instead of global variables.

Comment: What I need is what J.. pointed out. An easy way to have different variables in the different threads. Synchronizing would not work in my case. I believe that J.. answered effective in his comments above, i.e. either declaring separate variable or using a class. I already started thinking about the class option. Many thanks guys! Appreciated

Comment: Yes.  Class with code and data - method for the code, the 'globals', (yuk), ints/strings to hold error/success data. Create instances, preferably queue them to a pool of threads.  Forget the app-level or main-form globals: as others have commented, it's a hopeless design:(  You don't need the thread class to hold any state data - just descend from TObject.  You can easily test out the class without any extra threads by simply instantiating one in a main-form message-handler and calling the 'work' method.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to allocate different memory to each thread, so
> that I get three messages with sums 100?

There is a really easy way to allocate different memory to each thread and yet use the same declaration: Use the **threadvar** keyword.

Here is the code changed:

```
unit Execution;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs;

procedure CalculateSum;
procedure IncrementSum(var Sum: integer);

implementation

const
  NoOfTimes = 100;
threadvar                // <==== ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
  Sum: integer;

procedure CalculateSum;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    Sum := 0;
    for i := 0 to Pred(NoofTimes) do
    begin
        IncrementSum(Sum);
    end;
    ShowMessage('Sum = ' + IntToStr(Sum));
end;

procedure IncrementSum(var Sum: integer);
begin
    Inc(Sum);
    Sleep(10);
end;

end.
```

Comment: "Easy", but with all the headache of global variables... `threadvar` is a bit like lead acetate.  It tastes sweet at first, but after a while you start to feel the poison.  Use with care.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the right way to approach this. You want a variable of much more local scope than a thread var.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The OP do not want to rewrite too much code. He ask for an easy way to allocate different memory to each thread in *his* current code and threadvar is the easiest way. He said: "Hence, the easiest way to do so is to create a class for all the calculations of Execution.pas, right? I was hoping that there is a simpler way for my case (without high hopes though, to be honest)". He knows he has not done the best design and how he can do a better one next time. I gave him the quick and easy solution for the current code.

Comment: @fpiette if the OP wants to take shortcuts that's their decision but answers here on SO really should show case best practise. And frankly, taking shortcuts with multithreading invariably fails. Usually it's a false economy.

Comment: @J... indeed, threadvar could be a solution to the problem (I did not know it, so thanks again), however I agree with you that in the long run it will be a nightmare. As David Heffernan wrote, taking shortcuts with multithreading invariably fails.
The good with my code is that all the calculations in the Execution unit, employed 100% Execution variables. Hence it should be relatively easy to create a TExecution class. and create instances as you proposed in a post below.

Comment: Btw, I have one final question, if I may ask. When creating the instances of the TExecution class, there might be different threads that allocate the same memory simultaneoulsy, which causes the usual problem. What is the best way to avoid this? Many thanks again in advance!

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou I think that should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @J... I think you are right. I will do some background reading and post the question, when I feel 100% ready. Many thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using `TCriticalSection` in `System.SyncObjs` ?

Only one thread can enter the TCriticalSection at a time, so if a thread enters, modifies shared variables, and leaves, then each thread will wait for the others.

If you are spending most of the time in the TCriticalSection this won't help you scale, because your threads will be mostly waiting for the object, but it does ensure that only one thread is modifying the data protected with the TCriticalSection at a time.

So if your code is continually updating shared variables this will stop them clashing but not really provide the benefit of separate threads.  If, however, the threads are doing significant calculation without modifying variables then this allows that code to execute in parallel.

Comment: My problem is not that I want different threads to access shared variables. I was looking for way of declaring and uisng different instances of the global variables of the same unit in the different threads. Anyway, thanks for the reply